# How to interpret $(x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)) \in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I need help with the following, how should I interpret this notation?

> $$
> (x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)) \in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n] 
> $$

**1.** Does it mean "$x(t_1)$ is a element of the set $(a_1,b_1]$" and "$x(t_2)$ is a element of the set $(a_2,b_2]$", and so forth? 
So we have
\begin{align}
x(t_1)&\in (a_1,b_1] \\
x(t_2)&\in (a_2,b_2] \\
&\vdots \\
x(t_n)&\in (a_n,b_n] 
\end{align}

**2.** Or does the notation mean something like this
\begin{align} 
x(t_1)&\in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n] \\
x(t_2)&\in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n]  \\
&\vdots \\
x(t_n)&\in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n] 
\end{align}
I don't know how to phrase this notation. Does it have a meaning in this context?

**3.** Or maybe something like this
\begin{align}
(x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)) &\in (a_1,b_1] \\
(x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)) &\in (a_2,b_2] \\
&\vdots \\
(x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)) &\in (a_n,b_n] 
\end{align}
Same here, I don't know how to phrase this notation. Does it have a meaning in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: it means **1.**     Like $(x,y)\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use interpretation **1.**

$ (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n] $ is a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of intervals.

Elements of it are $n$-tuples, such as $(x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n)).$

Comment: for interpretation **2.**, there would not be parentheses before $x(t_1)$ and after $x(t_n)$; interpretation **3.** would mean an $n$-tuple is in an interval, which doesn't make sense

Comment: Okay, number **1** it is, thanks! Also, do you mean **2** would be correct if I instead had $$x(t_1), x(t_2), \dots, x(t_n) \in (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2] \times \dots \times (a_n,b_n]$$?

Comment: yes, then each $x(t_i)$ would be an element of the Cartesian product